# How do I define multiple directories maintaining directory-specific attributes in a proper way?

Tags: ansible

Take the following as an example:

```
    - name: setup jitsi-meet volumes (0/5)
      file:
        path: /srv/jitsi-meet/.jitsi-meet-cfg
        state: directory
        owner: root
        group: root
        mode: 0755

    - name: setup jitsi-meet volumes (1/5)
      file:
        path: /srv/jitsi-meet/.jitsi-meet-cfg/web
        state: directory
        owner: 2000
        group: 2000
        mode: 0644

    - name: setup jitsi-meet volumes (2/5)
      file:
        path: /srv/jitsi-meet/.jitsi-meet-cfg/prosody
        state: directory
        owner: root
        group: root
        mode: 0600
```

Is there a proper way in ansible to not only reduce these three separate tasks to one single task, but to maintain the possibility to modify owner, group and mode for each path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option would be to loop the list of files.

```
vars:
  my_files_dir: /srv/jitsi-meet/.jitsi-meet-cfg
  my_files:
    - path: "{{ my_files_dir }}"
      state: directory
      owner: "root"
      group: "root"
      mode: "0755"
    - path: "{{ my_files_dir }}/web"
      state: directory
      owner: "2000"
      group: "2000"
      mode: "0644"
    - path: "{{ my_files_dir }}/prosody"
      state: directory
      owner: "root"
      group: "root"
      mode: "0600"
tasks:
  - file:
      path: "{{ item.path }}"
      state: "{{ item.state }}"
      owner: "{{ item.owner }}"
      group: "{{ item.group }}"
      mode: "{{ item.mode }}"
    loop: "{{ my_files }}"
```

This can be simplified further with the parameters' default values

```
vars:
  my_files_dir: /srv/jitsi-meet/.jitsi-meet-cfg
  my_files:
    - path: "{{ my_files_dir }}"
    - path: "{{ my_files_dir }}/web"
      owner: "2000"
      group: "2000"
      mode: "0644"
    - path: "{{ my_files_dir }}/prosody"
      mode: "0600"
tasks:
  - file:
      path: "{{ item.path }}"
      state: "{{ item.state|default('directory') }}"
      owner: "{{ item.owner|default('root') }}"
      group: "{{ item.group|default('root') }}"
      mode: "{{ item.mode|default('0755') }}"
    loop: "{{ my_files }}"
```

Comment: You don't need the leading `{` and trailing `}` in all those dictionaries.